# ¿Cómo determinar el número menor y mayor de una lista de numero enteros positivos, y el promedio de estos números?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int numero=0,n,mayor,menor,w,i;

  do
  {
    cout<<"introducir numero";
    cin>>n;
    menor=n;
    mayor=n;
    numero=numero+1;
    w=numero;

    if (n<=menor)
    {
      menor=n;
    }
    else if (n>=mayor)
    {
      mayor=n;
    }
  }

  while (n>=0);
  cout<<"menor es"<<menor;
  cout<<"mayor es"<<mayor;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: El promedio lo calculas sumando todos los números y dividiendo entre la cantidad de números.

Answer (score 2):

Tu bloque `do-while` hace que cada vez que ingreses un número mayor que cero, las variables `mayor` y `menor` tomen este valor, observa como está funcionando tu código:

```
    do
      {
        cout<<"introducir numero";          //ingresando un número >0     ingresando un número<0
        cin>>n;                             //n=2                         n=-1
        menor=n;                            //menor=2                     menor=-1
        mayor=n;                            //mayor=2                     mayor=-1
        numero=numero+1;                    //numero+=1                   mumero+=1
        w=numero;

        if (n<=menor)                       //2<=2                        -1<=-1 -> será verdad siempre
        {
          menor=n;                          //menor=2                     menor=-1
        }
        else if (n>=mayor)                  //2>=2                        -1>=-1 -> será verdad siempre
        {
          mayor=n;                          //mayor=2                     mayor=-1
        }
      }
      while (n>=0);                         //continua el bucle           Termina el bucle
```

Si te diste cuenta, las condicionales siempre serán verdaderas, ya que estás comparando un número prácticamente con sigo mismo, y cuando ingreses un número negativo, el bloque `do-while` le dará una última pasada a las líneas antes de verificar el valor de `n`, por lo que que tus variables `mayor` y `menor` serán siempre el último número negativo que ingreses.

1. Lo primero a corregir son los valores iniciales para las variables `mayor` y `menor`, lo normal es que al ingresar el primer número válido (número entero positivo) ambas variables tomen este valor, pero solo al principio, es decir, esta asignación no debería estar dentro del bucle.
2. Lo segundo sería cambiar la ubicación de la lectura de datos dentro del bucle, para que este no considere dentro de los cálculos el número negativo ingresado, en este caso debería estar al final, justo antes de hacer la verificación de `n`.
3. Para calcular el promedio debes acumular todos los valores ingresados y también la cantidad de estos, al final sacar el promedio se reduce a dividir estas dos cantidades.

Juntando estas sugerencias e intentando modificar al mínimo tu código, este debería quedar mas o menos así:

```
int main() {
   int numero=0,n,mayor,menor,w=0,i;

   //primera lectura de datos fuera del bucle
   cout<<"introducir numero"<<endl;
   cin>>n;

   //validando el primer valor ingresado
   if (n<0){
     cout<<"No se ingresó ningún valor válido"<<endl;
     exit(-1);
   }
   //asignando el punto de partida de las variables mayor y menor
   menor=n;
   mayor=n;

   do
   {
     numero=numero+1;//contando la cantidad de datos ingresados
     w+=n;//acumulando los datos ingresados

     if (n<menor)
     {
       menor=n;
     }
     else if (n>mayor)
     {
       mayor=n;
     }
     //realizando una nueva lectura, ahora si dentro del bucle
     cout<<"introducir numero"<<endl;
     cin>>n;
   }
   while (n>=0);

   cout<<"menor es "<<menor<<endl;
   cout<<"mayor es "<<mayor<<endl;
   cout<<"promedio es "<<float(w)/numero<<endl;//la conversión a float es necesaria.
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para encontrar el elemento más pequeño y más grande en una colección, puedes usar [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) de la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm):

```
auto valores = { 0u, 9u, 1u, 8u, 2u, 7u, 3u, 6u, 4u, 5u };

auto [minimo, maximo] = std::minmax_element(std::begin(valores), std::end(valores));

std::cout << "Minimo: " << *minimo << '\n'
    << "Maximo: " << *maximo << '\n';
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> Minimo: 0
> Maximo: 9
> ```

Para calcular el promedio, puedes valerte de la función [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) de la cabecera [`<numeric>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/numeric):

```
auto valores = { 0u, 9u, 1u, 8u, 2u, 7u, 3u, 6u, 4u, 5u };

auto suma = std::accumulate(std::begin(valores), std::end(valores), .0);

std::cout << "Promedio: " << (suma / valores.size()) << '\n';
```

Acumulamos usando un `double` para que al dividir por la cantidad de elementos de la colección, el resultado se promocione a `double` y obtener así los decimales. El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> Promedio: 4.5
> ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDNTsMwEITP9VOsyqEJTUso/2naN0DiDggZZwmW/FM5NkJUfXXCxm0CSBw4fLJ3tJ4ZWWw2s1qItj2SRqhQIZTSNt4h12v2rXFVWyf96y/RBI1OijVj0njQXJokZVs24sFbeOPKOmxgBVvIQwY3xClxTSyIK@KMuCTOiYsAuyU7PL7X0khtMzJ9p/ORXBpfFQXJpDyhQo3GJ1F7xpqCD3Fptl9EUw1S2tlGVdjgoSxhfBvtCxh30/E@rLtOHsyEjUZxJSYPK3HqV4aeTdC878aFCDoo7vGfvTKY5390u3NWYyX76CRmnPT/OW/kByZp@rOKQx@cgXzJdm37KV4Ur5t2Rq4rMZ0u@Bc)</kbd>.